# How can i find the number of elements in the div tag in Selenium with Python. i mean how can i get 7 , so that i can run a loop to click next 7 times

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

Below is the code from a webpage i am scraping using slenium chrome driver with python, i want to know how i can get the number of elements in this i.e., 7 so i can loop accordingly through the pages

```
"""<div class="pagination__pages"><button class="pagination__page pagination__page--active" data-page="1">1</button>
    <button class="pagination__page" data-page="2">2</button>
    <button class="pagination__page" data-page="3">3</button>
    <button class="pagination__page" data-page="4">4</button>
    <button class="pagination__page" data-page="5">5</button>
    <button class="pagination__page" data-page="6">6</button>
    <button class="pagination__page" data-page="7">7</button></div>"""
```

Answer (score 0):

I would get the elements inside the div like this:

```
total_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/button") # Using your given html code
print(len(total_elements) # This should return 7
```

To find multiple elements (these methods will return a list):

- find_elements_by_name
- find_elements_by_xpath
- find_elements_by_link_text
- find_elements_by_partial_link_text
- find_elements_by_tag_name
- find_elements_by_class_name
- find_elements_by_css_selector

[Check related documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)